# Error about operator overloading when I try to compile this code

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Rice
{
    float price_per_kg, total_weight;
    public:
    Rice(float w)
    {
        price_per_kg = 10.0;
        total_weight = w;
    }
    void display_rice()
    { 
        cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"\tRice Details"<<endl;
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
        cout<<"Total weight\t : "<<total_weight<<endl;
        cout<<"Price perkg (RM): "<<price_per_kg<<endl;
        cout<<"Total (RM)\t : "<<total_weight*price_per_kg<<endl;
    }
};

class Product:public Rice
{
    float kg;
    public:
        Product operator+(const Product &p)
        {
            return Rice(kg + p.kg);
        }
        void Setdata()
        {
            cout << "Enter product's weight(kg): ";
            cin >> kg;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Product a, b;
    a.Setdata();
    b.Setdata();
    Rice h = a + b;
    h.display_rice();
}
```

I got this error:

> [Error] could not convert 'Rice((((Product*)this)->Product::kg +
> ((float)p.Product::kg)))' from 'Rice' to 'Product'

Is there any way to solve the error? I have tried to use other ways to solve but the question *requires* operator overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you a `Rice` isn't a `Product`.

Either you change the return type

```
Rice operator+(const Product &p)
```

Or you change the expression you return

```
{
    Product result = *this;
    result.kg += p.kg; // or some other things?
    return result;
}
```

Or you re-think your classes. Do you really mean that a `Product` is a `Rice` and not the other way around? At the moment a `Product` has both a `kg` member directly, and a `total_weight` member within the `Rice` base-subobject.